# Write a simple c++ function in objective c

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to make life a little bit easier for me. I get a lot of values from NSDictionary, like this:

```
//First, make sure the object exist 
if ([myDict objectForKey: @"value"])
{
     NSString *string = [myDict objectForKey: @"value"]; 
     //Maybe do other things with the string here... 
}
```

I have a file (Variables.h) where I store a lot of stuff to control the app. If would be nice to put a few helper methods in there. So instead of doing the above code, I would like to have a c++ function in the Variables.h, so I can just do this:

```
NSString *string = GetDictValue(myDictionary, @"value");
```

How do you write that c++ method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: GetDictValue(myDictionary, @"value"); 
    [myDictionaryobjectForKey: @"value"];

They have the same number of char... Why you think the first line is more useful than the second one?

Comment: I figure I needed to check if the object exist in the dictionary? The value is sometimes empty

Comment: @user1251004 what would your c++ function return in that case?

Comment: Which string? The empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose this is technically a c function, is c++ a strict requirement

```
static NSString* GetDictValue(NSDictionary* dict, NSString* key)
{
    if ([dict objectForKey:key])
    {
         NSString *string = [dict objectForKey:key]; 
         return string;
    }
    else 
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Consider using `id` and casting where necessary:

```
static id GetDictValue(NSDictionary* dict, NSString* key)
{
    if ([dict objectForKey:key])
    {
         id value = [dict objectForKey:key]; 
         return value;
    }
    else 
    {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: But if [dict objectForKey:key] doesn't return anything, what does the function return?

Comment: @MarcoPace: on ARM, the return value is in r0, so in that case `dict` will be returned, which is not correct. This function should handle the `else` case, too.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would rewrite your test like this to get rid of a lookup:

```
NSString *string = [myDict objectForKey: @"value"]; 
if (string)
{
     // Do stuff.
}
```

But if you want a default value for missing keys and it doesn't *have* to be a C++ function, I believe the more idiomatic solution would be to use a category to extend NSDictionary.

Thoroughly untested and uncompiled code:

```
@interface NSDictionary (MyNSDictionaryExtensions)
- (NSString*) objectForKey: (NSString*) key withDefaultValue: (NSString*) theDefault;
- (NSString*) safeObjectForKey: (NSString*) key;
@end

@implementation NSDictionary (MyNSDictionaryExtensions)
- (NSString*) objectForKey: (NSString*) key withDefaultValue: (NSString*) theDefault
{
    NSString* value = (NSString*) [self objectForKey: key];
    return value ? value : theDefault;
}
- (NSString*) safeObjectForKey: (NSString*) key
{
    return [self objectForKey: key withDefaultValue: @"Nope, not here"];
}
@end
```